# How to create a multistage docker file for Azure Functions and Playwright?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-functions, docker-multi-stage-build

I am setting up some testing tooling for my team using Playwright. Now we are experimenting with Azure Functions so I thought it would be fun to combine the two.

I am deploying my Azure Function using a docker container, and have included Playwright in there. There is also a base image available for Playwright, so I would be interested to combine these two to make the docker image smaller.

I think I need something like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.28.0-jammy as playwright

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:4-node18

COPY --from=playwright ??? ???

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

RUN cd /home/site/wwwroot && \
    npm install && \
    npm run build
```

So I'm thinking I first get the playwright image, download what is needed, and then copy that to the functions image. I just have no idea what to copy, and can't find anything related to it.

Does anyone have an idea? Am I even thinking along the right lines?

Answer (score 0):

`COPY --from=playwright` command is used to copy the required files from the Playwright image.

`COPY --from=playwright /usr/bin/playwright /usr/bin/playwright`

- You can follow the below Docker file to achieve your requirement.

***Example:***

```
#Stage 1

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.28.0-jammy as playwright

RUN apt-get install -y nodejs 
RUN npm install playwright-core

#Stage 2 

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:4-node18 
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \ AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true  
COPY --from=playwright /usr/bin/playwright /usr/bin/playwright 
COPY --from=playwright /usr/lib/node_modules/playwright-core /usr/lib/node_modules/playwright-core 
COPY . /home/site/wwwroot 
RUN cd /home/site/wwwroot && \ 
    npm install && \ 
    npm start
```

***Stage 1:***

Using Playwright base image. Installing required Node.js and the `playwright-core` package

***Stage 2:***

Copying the necessary files from the stage1 to the nodejs Azure Function image.
Building the Nodejs Azure Function by installing the required dependencies, copying the source code, and running the start command.

- Build this Dockerfile using the following command:

```
docker build -t <Image:tag> .
```

***References:***

[How to create a multi stage Dockerfile | DevOps Tutorial (devopspilot.com)](https://devopspilot.com/content/docker/tutorials/Dockerfile/03-create-multi-stage-dockerfile.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your example! When I run it I get an error stating npm ERR! Tracker "idealTree" already exists. It happens at RUN npm install playwright-core
. I think it has something to do with not setting a WORKDIR. Do you know what the work dir should be?